# canonicals skype repository disturbes updates (apt-get)

Tags: apt, updates, skype, repository

Following situation: I tried to install skype wie the USC, but uninstalled it again since it was an old version and did not work correctly. So I installed Skype from skypes website.
But it seems like there is a problem with the old skype repository. The update manager wont update, apt-get gives error messages:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

It seems to be a canonical repository missing/not working. When I try to activate the repository in the package manager it says I'm not allowed to, without asking for a password. I can't see how to activate them in the sources.list.

I'm on a fresh installed Ubuntu 12.10 computer, without any old or backuped data. My internet connection works without any problems. I can post this text, ping the ips given in the error messages, everything works. Except apt-get.

UPDATE
There seems to be an additional affection. I can't use auto-completion in terminal when I try to install something using "sudo apt-get install package-..." which is also really annoying.

Comment: If you actually go the the addresses, they don't exist. [When I try to activate the repository in the package manager it says I'm not allowed to, without asking for a password] input **your** password. If you want Skype, download it from the Skype site.

Comment: As I wrote above I finally did install it from the website. But when I do that, it marks skype installed again, but the newer version. Problem still exists. I tried reinstallations already. And I'd love to input my password but it did NOT ask. Sorry maybe that wasn't clear, I'm not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I finally got it fixed. The Problem was a third entry of a "Canonical Partner - Added by Software enter". It was not on the top of the list beside the other partner repositorys so I didn't recognize it. To deactivate it I had to use sudo, but since it didn't ask for a password I had to use:

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

and enter my password. Then I was able to deactivate. Updating the system is working again, also apt-get itself and the auto-completion.

Answer (score 2):

I could unfortunately not fix this through the graphical interface as I could not find the ppa anywhere listed.

Instead I looked in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`
Where I found two files

```
archive.canonical.com_commercial-ppa-uploaders_skype_ubuntu.list.save
archive.canonical.com_commercial-ppa-uploaders_skype_ubuntu.list
```

These files contained the the faulty links.
I removed these files and the problem disappeared

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive.canonical.com_commercial-ppa-uploaders_skype_ubuntu.list* ~/someOtherDir/
```